# const *char to char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers

Noob Question time: In an qt widget application, I have to take several inputs from user(in QString) and then convert it to char arrays so I can put them into system(), and pass the output to the user. I can do the conversion, but the problem is how to get char* to a char array so that I can use that array as an argument for system()?? I tried several things but no progress.

Here's my code:

```
    QByteArray ba = lText.toLatin1();
    const char *dir[] = { ba.data() };
    QString file = ui->fileName_Edit->text();
    QByteArray ba2 = file.toLatin1();
    const char *fileN[] = {ba2.data()};
    char directory[100], f[60];
    strcpy(dir, directory);
    strcpy(fileN, f);
    char cmd[1000] = "ls " + directory;
    system(cmd);
```

Comment: @BaummitAugen `std::string` for `QString` or `const char*` ?? Example code maybe ??

Comment: Just do not use C `str...` functions, `char` arrays or `char` pointers. Never, ever. You have `QString`, use it throughout. Once you need to convert a `QString` to a `char*` to pass it to some function, convert and pass it. `qstr.toLatin1().data()` should do. Do not manipulate converted value in any way.

Comment: Do NOT use `toLatin1`. Use `toLocal8Bit` or `toUtf8` instead to handle international characters.

Comment: in addition don't use system for this, you can use the QDir::entryInfoList to get the list of files in a directory